# Unable to install R in Cent OS 7

Tags: r, centos

I am trying to install R in Cent OS 7. Using this command

```
$ sudo yum install R
```

Getting this error

```
texlive-ae-svn15878.1.4-38.el7 FAILED
http://del-mirrors.extreme- 
ix.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/texlive-ae-                                                                                        
svn15878.1.4-38.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended 
downl                                                                                    
oad. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=base clean metadata
Trying other mirror.
texlive-luaotfload-bin-svn1857 FAILED
http://del-mirrors.extreme- 
ix.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/texlive-lua                                                                                        
otfload-bin-svn18579.0-38.20130427_r30134.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno -1] Package 
doe                                                                                        
s not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=base clean 
metad                                                                                        
ata
Trying other mirror.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an `R` problem, but a `yum` problem.

It's likely the hashes don't match, and possibly because of how stable, i.e. so far behind, Centos generally is. Either that, or the repo version doesn't match.

Try a `yum clean all` followed by a `yum update`. Then try again.

Comment: @NikhilSinghal Try seeing if [these instructions](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/redhat/README) help at all. It's still possible the repo is out of sync.